# Why isn't this web-scraping code returning any results?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am trying get the headlines of each and everyday from economic times India from 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31, this is what I have tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
from dateutil import rrule 
from calendar import monthrange
import csv

def read_url(year, month, starttime):
    url = f'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-{year},month-{month},starttime-{starttime}.cms'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve data from the website. Response status code: {response.status_code}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_starttime(year,month,day):  
    date1= '1990-12-30'    
    timestamp1 = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple())            
    date2 = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(day)    
    timestamp2 = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d').timetuple())

    starttime=((timestamp2 - timestamp1)/86400)
    return str(starttime).replace(".0", "")

headlines_from = '2020-01-01'
headlines_to = '2020-10-31'

headlines_datetime_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(headlines_from, '%Y-%m-%d')
headlines_datetime_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(headlines_to, '%Y-%m-%d')

for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY,dtstart= headlines_datetime_from,until=headlines_datetime_to):
    year = int(dt.strftime('%Y'))
    month = int(dt.strftime('%m'))

for day in range (1,(monthrange(year,month)[1]+1)):
    starttime = get_starttime(year,month,day)
    data_str_eng = str(year) + '-'+ '{:02d}'.format(month) + '-' +'{:02d}'.format(day)
   
    headlines = []
    soup = read_url(year,month,starttime)
    for td in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'contentbox5'}):
        for headline in td.findAll('a'):
            if 'archive' not in headline.get('href'):
                if len(headline.contents)>0:
                    if headline.contents[0] not in headlines:                       
                         headlines.append(headlines.contents[0])
    time.sleep(1)

    file = open(f'C:/Users/somar/OneDrive - Technological University of the Shannon Midwest/mythesis/mynew thesis topic/economic_news_headlines_{data_str_eng}.csv', 'w')
    with file:
        write = csv.writer(file, escapechar = '\\' , quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for item in headlines:
            write.writerow([item,])
```

The code is running properly but i am getting 0kb data files.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I ran your code from the first to `soup = read_url(year,month,starttime)` and it raised your exception. Also, `headlines.append(headlines.contents[0])` will throw AttributeError as `headlines` is your list; it should be `headline`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The issue is probably with code that creates the dates for your url. Perhaps those urls are sending you to an "empty" page that doesn't contain the html your searching for. Respectfully, it seems like you have spent little time troubleshooting your code, so please do so. If you run into other problems come back and I'll help you out.

Note: I changed `read_url` to take url's just for the sake of trouble shooting. I also passed 2 new arguments to the `open` function to fix an encoding error and to not have a newline every other row (in the csv), respectively.

```
def read_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve data from the website. Response status code: {response.status_code}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2022,month-12,starttime-44911.cms"
    
    # get sites page source, pass it to bs obj, return bs obj
    soup = read_url(url)

    headlines = []
    for td in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'contentbox5'}):
        for headline in td.findAll('a'):
            if 'archive' not in headline.get('href'):
                if len(headline.contents)>0:
                    if headline.contents[0] not in headlines:                       
                         headlines.append(headline.contents[0])
    # print(headlines)

    # write to file using utf-8 encoding and without adding a newline every other row
    file = open(f'PATH/economic_news_headlines.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='')

    with file:
        write = csv.writer(file, escapechar = '\\' , quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for item in headlines:
            write.writerow([item,])
```